# Gridview rebind data with new parameters

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datasource, code-behind

OK, so I need to change the values stored in my gridview based on input from user.
I used to filter it 100% with javascript, but it turns out that it needs to be paged, so that wont work. Instead, I have to call on the datasource again, but with parameters from the textbox.

I've figured out that I must call a function in code behind and from there call DataBind(), but I dont even know where to start. Please help

I know that I ought to post some code to show that I've made an effort, but I really dont have anything to show. i guess it would be something along these lines?:

```
protected void ReBind(string sParameter)
{
    SqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("parameterName", sParameter);
    myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

But obviously I'm fumbling in the dark here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this worked out fine:

```
protected void ReBind(String sParameter)
{
   SqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Remove(SqlDataSource.SelectParameters["parameterName"]);
   SqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("parameterName", sParameter);
   myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a update button
2. Write method for update function

   public int update_method(string ParameterName)
   {

   ```
   module c = new module();
   c.DB_Connection();
   int i;
   string QRY = "UPDATE TableName SET Parameter_Name='" + ParameterName + "' WHERE Parameter_Name='" + ParameterName + "'";
    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(QRY, c.con);
    i = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return i;
   }
   ```
3. on button click
     protected void ButtonUpdate_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          update_method(ParameterNametxt.Text);
      }
   update_method(farm, common_obj);